# For each function starts with last value of array instead of value 0 / document.getElementById("button").click() doesnt click

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

**UPDATE:**

Hi there!

After I got a very helpfull answer on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764447/im-having-some-arrayi-is-undefined-error-and-i-dont-find-a-way-of-working-aro), I got to the next result.

To give you a brief explanation, I filter all GENTXXXX from one table, use the GENTXXXX to open a webpage containing information about GENTXXXX, and there I want to force a buttonpress which resets all GENTXXXX information, after that I force a buttonpress which confirms the reset. Please review my code and I would be great if you have a look at my two problems below! Thx a lot!

```
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#UnitItems td");
let ids = [];

tds.forEach((td) => {
    if (td.textContent.includes("GENT")) {
        spatieWeg = td.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "");  //removes space in front of "GENT"
        ids.push(spatieWeg);
    }
});

console.log("extractGent done");
console.log(ids);
debugger; //to check if ids got all the correct values in it.

function processWindow(i) {
    var newWindow = window.open("/NetViewer/LineupsCommand/AddUnitInformation?unitID=" + ids[i] + "&lineupName=Z_GENT_1_INT_MAANDAG_1&agencyID=Z_GENT", "_self");

    newWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var resetButton = newWindow.document.getElementById('btnResetAllEmployees');
        if (resetButton) {
            resetButton.click();
        }

        var addButton = newWindow.document.getElementById('btnAddUnitInformation');
        if (addButton) {
            addButton.click();
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    console.log(ids[i]);
    processWindow(i);
}
```

The problem I have right now is this. First off all I have 25 values in 'ids', when running function `processWindow(i)` it takes the 24th value from 'ids'. Not value 0. After that the code stops running, because of the second problem.

The second problem, even when opening the 24the value, it does not automate the two click's.

I already tried `setTimeOut '5000'` in front of the button.clicks. But It just does not "click". I used setTimeOut because I thought the page needed the time to fully load.

In console I tried to use `document.getElementById('btnResetAllEmployees').click()`, and that seems to work.

Is the code executed in the correct order?

and this is the html behind te code, it has a click event attached to it.

```
<input type="button" class="secondary-btn" style="position:static;" id="btnResetAllEmployees" value="Wis alle personeel / toestellen">
```

I cannot figure it out,... If you need additional information, I would like to hear it.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to ask why you are clicking buttons on a new page however, I'm more than happy to answer your questions.

1. I'm not sure what you mean by 24th item. I can ensure your that `.forEach` does not run backward. It's more likely that your selector is not behaving the way you expect.
2. The reason your button clicks are not working is because your new window uses `"_self"` as the target. This causes the new window to replace the current tab, thus stopping execution of your code. To make your button clicks work, you need to make sure the new window opens in a new tab.

I went ahead and cleaned up your code. This removes a lot of duplication and should fix the "bugs" you were experiencing.

```js
function processWindow(unitId) {
    const newWindow = window.open(`/NetViewer/LineupsCommand/AddUnitInformation?unitID=${unitId}&lineupName=Z_GENT_1_INT_MAANDAG_1&agencyID=Z_GENT`);

    newWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
        newWindow.document.getElementById('btnResetAllEmployees')?.click();
        newWindow.document.getElementById('btnAddUnitInformation')?.click();
    });
}

const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#UnitItems td");
tds.forEach((td) => {
    if (!td.textContent.includes("GENT")) {
        return;
    }

    const unitId = td.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "");  //removes space in front of "GENT"
    processWindow(unitId)
});
```

Comment: Thx for your reaction Joe! Let me answer, the not asked question. Because I really dont know how to handle this otherwise. Is there a possibility to push the click.event behind the button, without opening a new.window? Like somekind of pushEvent?

Your first point, let me explain a bit further. When running the code, the first page it opens is ids[24], not ids[0]. 

Your second point makes total sense! Thanks for explaining this to me.

The code you provided @JoeHartzell gives me a "redeclaration error of const tds"

Thx for helping me find a solution!

Comment: My code doesn't give you the error. You must be copying and pasting the code and "tds" is executing multiple times. Change it to "let tds". 

There are tons of tools for browser automation. If your goal is to automate doing a browser task, I would recommend looking at puppeteer (https://pptr.dev/). It is specifically made to do what you are asking.

Comment: The reason that the 24th page is opened "first" is because the code is running very fast. The 24th page is the last one that you see. The loop has already executed for the first 23. If you added a delay to the execution you would see that the other 23 pages where opened.

Comment: Thx for your answer @JoeHartzell. I already looked at puppeteer. The thing is my admin does not allow any additional installations. So I tried the code you provided, made the let change and it works! But as you say, when opening the first webpage, the script stops running. So ideal, I must find a way to run the script behind the buttons on the second page,... without opening that page?

Comment: This question is solved! I'll post my solution in a new answer to this question. Feel free to provide commentary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JoeHartzell for pushing me in the right direction!

This is the script that does the trick, it opens a new tab, executes a task, closes the tab and continues the script.

```
function processWindow(unitId) {
const newTab = window.open(`/NetViewer/LineupsCommand/AddUnitInformation?unitID=${unitId}&lineupName=Z_GENT_2_INT_DINSDAG_1&agencyID=Z_GENT`, "_blank");

if (newTab) {
    newTab.addEventListener('load', function() {
        newTab.document.getElementById('btnResetAllEmployees')?.click();
        newTab.document.getElementById('btnAddUnitInformation')?.click();
        
        // Close the tab after performing actions
        setTimeout(function() {
            newTab.close();
        }, 100); // Adjust the delay as needed
    });
} else {
    console.error('Popup blocker prevented opening a new tab.');
}
}

let tds = document.querySelectorAll("#UnitItems td");
let index = 0;

function openNextTab() {
    if (index < tds.length) {
        const td = tds[index];
        if (td.textContent.includes("GENT")) {
            const unitId = td.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "");  // removes space in front of "GENT"
            processWindow(unitId);
        }
        index++;

        // Open the next tab after a delay (adjust the delay as needed)
        setTimeout(openNextTab, 100);
    }
}

// Start opening tabs one at a time
openNextTab();
```

Next thing to do, make a dropdown menu, to change the **Z_GENT_2_INT_DINSDAG_1** value with, for example, **Z_GENT_3_INT_WOENSDAG_1** in window.open(/NetViewer/LineupsCommand/AddUnitInformation?unitID=${unitId}&lineupName=**Z_GENT_2_INT_DINSDAG_1**&agencyID=Z_GENT, "_blank");

Thx community!

Comment: Can you at least upvote my answer? Since it was helpful it would be nice to have some credit for it. Your "questions" are also incredibly hard for others to answer 100% correctly because there is a LOT of missing context. Also your answer while it may work is incredibly messy for several reasons; unnecessary recursive function, managing multiple delays (not actually blocking the code), unneeded index.

Comment: Hi, thx for your message! I understand what you are saying. I dont have any background in coding and I'm trying to learn by fail and error, searching/reading the internet, feedback like yours. I would like to give you an upvote, the thing is, I dont have enough reputation to do. I would thank you a lot for your time.